# Which technologies are part of the HTML5 specification?

Tags: html, w3c

After some years I came across this question again and wanted to update it, as it was previously not clear enough. As a web developer we deal with many different web technologies and most people just subsume them into HTML5, but apparently not all of them are actually part of HTML5. So the question is, which technologies are part of HTML5 and which are just other web technologies.

When I initially asked this question back in 2015, the HTML5 specification was still relatively new and it was not entirly clear, which technologies belonged to HTML5 and which technologies were just commonly called HTML5. One of the main reasons for this confusion was the existence of competing HTML standards published by W3C and WHATWG, which considered different technologies part of HTML5. Those standards have initially been very similiar but diverged more and more over time due to different design decisions. The following image, which is used in the [HTML5 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), clearly shows
how different technologies can be categorized in the context of HTML5.

[image]

In 2019, W3C and WHATWG agreed that only WHATWG continues working on the HTML standard, so that the conflict between the standards could be resolved. In order to know what is part of HTML5 now, we can simply check the HTML Living Standard provided by WHATWG to see which technologies are defined as part of HTML5.

Comment: You have a recently history of off-topic or downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5),

> HTML5 is the latest evolution of the standard that defines HTML. The
>   term represents two different concepts:
>
> - It is a new version of the *language* HTML, with new elements, attributes, and behaviors,
> - and a larger set of **technologies** that allows more diverse and powerful Web sites and applications. This set is sometimes called
>     *HTML5 & friends* and often shortened to just *HTML5*.

So those aren't part of HTML5 in the first sense, but they are in the second one.